# How to block urls on a web view using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I need to block a certain part of the website from the web view because Apple will not approve that part of the website. How do I code it to block those urls and just stay on the current page?

(I am developing the application for a company and I am not their website developer and their guy is not very responsive so I cannot just remove the hyperlinks.)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's weird. Just remove those hyperlinks from the website!

Comment: @Raptor I am developing the application for a company and I am not their website developer so I can't do that and the web guy isn't answering at all and I need it accepted it soon. So I am trying to fix this on the application.

Comment: That's a terrible UX . However, you can use `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` delegate to intercept the clicks and block the links from loading.

Comment: @Raptor I have other pages so how would I block just two specific links instead of generalized hyperlinks

Comment: Read the documentation! You can obtain the URL from the delegate & block them specifically.

Comment: @Raptor I cannot find it in the documentation. It seems generalized, not how to specifically block them. Any idea where I am missing it?

Comment: @Raptor I can't find the documentation at all.

Comment: @Raptor can you link me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution.

One is to prevent it in UIWebViewDelegate function `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`.

Another is that server control this web show when it is really online.This will cheat Apple to pass your APP.

Comment: @JohnTirrell Server change online state and you show that web in code.

Comment: I have an app rep reviewing it over the phone so it's not about the code, he will click around.